Understanding the volatile Modifier in the Context of x86 Architecture and the Java Memory Model (JMM)
I have a question regarding the Java Memory Model (JMM), particularly in the context of x86 architecture, which I find quite intriguing. One of the most confusing and often debated topics is the volatile modifier.
I've heard a lot of misconceptions suggesting that volatile effectively forbids the use of cached values for fields marked with this modifier. Some even claim it prohibits the use of registers. However, as far as I understand, these are oversimplified notions. I've never encountered any instructions that explicitly forbid using caches or registers for storing such fields. I'm not even sure if such behavior is technically possible.
So, my question is directed at experts in x86 architecture: What actually happens under the hood? What semantics does the volatile modifier guarantee? From what I've seen, it seems to implement a full memory barrier using the LOCK prefix combined with the add 0 instruction.
Let's settle this debate once and for all.
P.S. I'm really tired of hearing false claims from my fellow programmers about volatile. They keep repeating the same story about cache usage, and I strongly feel they are terribly mistaken!
I have researched the Java Memory Model (JMM) and the use of the volatile modifier. I expected to find clear explanations on how volatile works in the context of x86 architecture, specifically regarding its impact on caching and register usage. However, I encountered conflicting information and misconceptions. I am seeking clarification from experts to understand the true semantics and behavior of volatile on x86 systems.

Hmm, I think the first thing here is that it might be kind of bad to try to think of an implementation this way.  Whatever they use now, the implementation could change later, and your mental model would go out the window.  It's best to read the Java language specification, and also Java Concurrency in Practice by Brian Goetz is highly recommended.

What semantics does the volatile modifier guarantee?  This I feel is way too broad to ask here.  Again, reading the specification is required.  What are you confused about?  What part of volatile's semantics do you feel are not settled?  I think much of its semantics are well understood, so what is left?

The purpose of a memory model is to hide platform specifics from the users of the language.

Site for mentioned book: Java Concurrency in Practice by Brian Goetz et al.

Java Language and Virtual Machine Specifications

Regarding "a lot of misconceptions", be aware that the nature of volatile changed with the re-invention of the Java Memory Model (JMM). Be sure to avoid any old outdated content published from the early years of Java..

Your questions are somewhat at odds. "What semantics does volatile guarantee" is 100% a question about the Java Memory Model and has absolutely not one iota to do with architecture. Whereas 'what actually happens under the hood' is a question that has absolutely not one iota to do with the JMM and everything to do with the specific JVM impl you are using (specifically, its impl on x86). In fact, only the tuple [JVM vendor, JVM version, architecture] leads to an answer.

Here's the key issue with your question: There is an ocean of difference between those 2 concepts. The thing is, 'colouring within the lines' in regards to what the JMM promises volatile will guarantee means your code will work. Today. Tomorrow. Next year. On an arm chip. On a chip that hasn't been invented yet. In contrast, if you write it 'specifically in regards to how it works under the hood', it will work today. On that specific chip. With this specific JVM vendor. On this specific version. On this specific OS. Change anything and your code probably breaks.

In that latter context, hopefully you understand: "How it works precisely is almost entirely irrelevant to a java programmer (intriguing for a VM engineer possibly just as a lesson) - what you're asking for is extremely esoteric". Which is fine, it's a good question! But, know that it is somewhat unlikely to get an answer; very few people can meaningfully answer it. You might want to add a bounty. If on the other hand you just want an explanation of volatile, then.. just read the JMM. We can't guess what blogposts you have read and what bulloney they peddled you.

Hence if the question is 'please explain volatile to me', no can do. You're going to have to explain which misconceptions you specifically labour under, which resources you have read that you question, which parts of the JMM (which is the authoritative source, and the only one you should probably be reading here; there's a lot of horsepuckey around on what volatile does as you have found; the trick is, that comes in many disgusting flavours so we can't tell you what's wrong with what's in your head without knowing exactly what you read).

@markspace I have read the specification and tried to understand it as much as my current level of knowledge allows. The thing is, I have repeatedly heard from different people statements that I have never encountered in the specification. Where does this widespread belief that volatile prohibits caching come from? Have you ever heard similar claims from fellow programmers? Just yesterday, someone with 15 years of programming experience told me this but provided no proof. I'm trying to understand if this is true, but I can't find any confirmation anywhere.

@markspace Why do people give this definition to this modifier when its semantics are much deeper and are primarily intended to ensure the happens-before relationship, as I understand it?

@BasilBourque Yes, I am aware of the different nature of this modifier when comparing J2SE 5.0 and earlier versions. I know that it ensures atomicity for long and double types, particularly in 32-bit systems. It effectively introduces a full memory barrier (as a consequence) and prohibits certain reorderings that could break the happens-before semantics. It seems to me that the essence lies in the happens-before semantics. It's unclear why there is so much discussion about the CPU cache. Often, all discussions about this modifier do not go beyond the cache.

@rzwitserloot Dear friend, thank you for your detailed responses! I understand that this modifier is more about providing certain guarantees. It's about more abstract concepts rather than a specific implementation. Undoubtedly, implementations can vary and may change over time. On one architecture, it will be implemented one way, and on another, it may (and most likely will) be implemented differently. There is no problem with that, and I fully understand it. Moreover, I realize that established implementations can also change (even daily, if necessary).

@rzwitserloot This is an interesting modifier that primarily makes one think and adds headaches for compiler developers who need to ensure that guarantees are upheld at all levels, corresponding to the happens-before principle. But please correct me if I am misunderstanding something... Is it acceptable to simplify everything to the level of the cache?

@rzwitserloot Seriously, wherever I look and whoever I talk to about this topic (at least in my personal circle), everyone starts insisting that the difference is only that volatile values are read directly from main memory (RAM) and effectively bypass the cache. Furthermore, they claim that such values are not cached at all if marked with this modifier. I believe this is a strange misconception since the specification does not mention this. At the machine instruction level, I haven't observed anything like this even with detailed disassembly at runtime.

@rzwitserloot The question is how to correctly understand all this. Should we just think about "direct reading from memory" for simplicity (even though it's much more complex in reality), or should we understand that this is a matter of semantics and happens-before relationships?

@Lexoid The commonly stated 'it prevents caching' is because it is an overly simplistic and not entirely correct intuition, but useful in a pinch perhaps. I don't think more explanation is necessary. If you find this slightly incorrect oversimplification annoying or useless, don't listen to it. The JMM is the authoritative source. "Oft repeated unfounded rumours" are not.

The problem is, the JMM does not mention the concept of 'cache'. It talks in terms of observability. Instead of using the sentence 'each thread may or may not cache any field', which implies a hardware implementation, the JMM uses the sentence 'Any thread may or may not observe an update to a field that another thread did', which boils down to the same notion but without implying anything about how the hardware works.

A volatile will not prevent using cache. This is critical to understand because there is a lot of bad information about there, and volatile preventing caching is an excellent way to figure out if the information is bad.
I'm not going to dig into the JMM itself since you question is about the X86 and the X86.  X86 is a strong memory model and will only allow for an older write to be reordered with a newer load to a different address due to write buffer. So what is needed (depending on the situation) is a [StoreLoad] between the store and the load.

There are many different ways to implement a [StoreLoad] including an MFENCE. But the JVM uses a lock addl 0, on the beginning of the stack since that will not be contended and is very likely already in the cache.
How it works: a [StoreLoad] fence will prevent any newer load from being executed till all earlier stores have been drained to the coherent cache (flushing the store buffer to the cache is something I frequently see, but it isn't how it works). Waiting for the store buffer to be drained can be a very costly process because there could be many stores in the store buffer.

And for each store, it could be that its cacheline needs to be invalidated in the caches of other cores. The number of concurrent outstanding stores to the cache is limited by the number of line fill buffers (LFBs). So it can take quite some time for the store buffer to be drained and this will prevent any instruction relying on the loaded values to be performed.
Please understand that thinking in terms of FENCES can be useful for performance, but it is a bad mental model.
https://shipilev.net/blog/2016/close-encounters-of-jmm-kind/#myth-barriers-are-sane

@rzwitserloot I completely agree with you! Over the past six months, as I’ve revisited this topic, I’ve come to understand that tying it too closely to hardware isn’t the right approach. As for the prohibition of caching, it’s indeed a myth, and I’ve managed to substantiate this. The assumption of direct writes to memory makes sense due to the regular commit from the Store Buffer when writing to a volatile field, but this does not imply a prohibition of caching. Of course, if we need to read a value, the cache is used just as it was before.

@pveentjer
After analyzing the situation, I have indeed concluded that lock addl 0 is used solely to enforce the semantics of a memory barrier. However, the operation also triggers the commit of writes relative to the hardware thread executing the operation, as I understand it; otherwise, it would be impossible to ensure the happens-before guarantees. And yes, I am not talking about a complete flush of the store buffer but specifically about a commit. The changes are pushed into the buffer, initiating the cache coherence protocols.

@pveentjer At least, this is how I was able to understand it, as incomplete writes are a "bottleneck" that would inevitably need to be completed to ensure hb guarantees.

What is needed to implement [StoreLoad] is that later loads are stalled until all preceding writes are committed from the store buffer into the coherence cache. This will guarantee that older stores can't be reordered with newer loads to a different address.  (retired) writes are already moved from the store buffer into the coherence cache as fast as possible, independent of any [StoreLoad] barriers.

@pveentjer Correct, but doesn’t the semantics of the barrier itself initiate the process of writing to the L1d cache? Writes can remain in the store buffer for an indefinite period, but instructions with semantics like memory barriers are more likely to initiate the commit process itself. Or am I mistaken in my assumptions?

@DmytroKostenko a memory barrier doesn't have any influence on the storebuffer and cache interaction. The storebuffer on the X86 is a FIFO conveyor belt and it will shuffle the stores to the coherent L1d as fast as possible. And even though stores can execute out of order, they retire and are committed to the L1d in program order (hence store/store ordering is preserved). No barrier has any influence on this process. The only thing that is needed for a [StoreLoad] barrier, is to delay the execution of newer loads till all older stores are drained from the store buffer in the L1d.

By delaying the execution of newer loads till all older stores are committed to the coherence cache, the CPU guarantees that older stores can't be reordered with newer loads to different addresses.

@pveentjer I realized my mistake. So, when speaking about the semantics of a memory barrier, it would be more accurate to say that it simply guarantees that before we proceed further, all preceding stores will be fully completed. It is a kind of synchronization mechanism that forces us to wait. Please correct me if I misunderstood it again.

You are almost there. Before any later loads (in program order) will start (so load their value from the coherent cache), all earlier stores (in program order) need to have been completed (so committed to the coherence cache). So only loads are delayed, other instructions can execute perfectly fine.

@pveentjer I have just one clarification for you. I genuinely don’t understand the following: if the store buffer operates "independently" or "autonomously," why can a value written to a field that is not marked with the volatile modifier theoretically be held (potentially) indefinitely, with no guarantee that it will ever be seen by other threads executing on other CPU cores? What, in this case, is the primary source of "holding" the value from being written to the cache and triggering the cache coherence protocol?

@pveentjer In the sources I’ve encountered, they all say the same thing: that the store buffer is almost the sole and primary source of this holding. If it operates independently and doesn’t require additional instructions, I don’t understand the root of the problem.

I don't know of any existing ISAs/microarchitecture whereby a store isn't seen for an indeterminate amount of time. But one source of such behavior could be the JIT e.g. when it hoists a variable out of a loop.
A store buffer isn't a source of holding a value indefinitely. The store buffer needs to be drained ASAP to make space for new stores. Keep in mind that a store buffer has very limited capacity (something like 100 on newest intel microarchitectures)

@pveentjer I’ve read a bit more on this topic and must respectfully disagree. Specifically, there is information regarding Intel processors that contradicts the assertion that the store buffer operates entirely autonomously and cannot be indirectly manipulated using instructions. In particular, Section 11.10 (Store Buffer) of Volume 3 of the Intel SW Developer's Guide mentions that instructions like MFENCE, SFENCE, and operations using the LOCK prefix ensure that the contents of the store buffer are always drained to memory.

@pveentjer If you download the combined document in full from Intel's official website, this information can be found on page 3545 in Section 13.10 STORE BUFFER.

@pveentjer According to Intel SDM (Volume 3, Section 13.10 "Store Buffer"), the contents of the store buffer are always drained to memory in the following situations: (1) when an exception or interrupt is generated, (2) for P6 and newer, when a serializing instruction (e.g., CPUID, IRET) is executed, (3) when an I/O instruction is executed, (4) when a LOCK operation is performed, (5) for P6 and newer, when a BINIT operation is performed, (6) for Pentium III and newer, when using SFENCE to order stores, and (7) for Pentium 4 and newer, when using MFENCE to order stores.

That the SB is drained to memory, doesn't mean there is a drain button that gets pressed in certain cases like fences. It only means that certain operations are delayed until the store buffer is drained up to some point.

@pveentjer Overall, I agree. I think this understanding is, at the very least, a safe one. The manual only points out the processes that occur when certain instructions are executed, but this does not imply that these processes need to be manually controlled. Nevertheless, the guarantees of draining are necessary to achieve the semantics ensured by the instruction. It is possible that this is indeed accomplished through waiting. I can’t provide deeper insights since the material does not offer low-level details on such mechanisms.

I also had the toilet flush model for some time but people like BeeOnRope gave me better insights.
https://media.diy.com/is/image/KingfisherDigital/uk-home-living-traditional-high-level-pan-cistern-with-flush-chain-flush-pipe-kit-including-white-wooden-seat-and-chrome-hinges~0658556128596_01c_MP?$MOB_PREV$&$width=1396&$height=1396

@pveentjer It turns out that everything is more complicated. You know what’s confusing? The guide explicitly mentions the concept of “draining” and provides a specific list of instructions whose execution ensures this very draining semantics. Nothing else comes to mind but the toilet flush analogy! :) It's a pity that we'll probably never know the absolute truth since some things are unlikely to be disclosed due to corporate considerations.

It doesn't make any sense to not drain 'continuously' because the store buffer has limited capacity and it can take quite some time to get rid of the stores due to the cache coherence latency (so issuing an RFO and waiting for the results). Assume there would be a drain button, what happens when the store buffer is full and no operation triggering a drain is in sight?

@pveentjer How did I see it? Draining, in my understanding, occurred both automatically and could be triggered using the instructions listed above. In the context of instructions, this makes sense as it allows them to maintain the required semantics. As for automatic operation, draining could occur on its own in the event of the buffer filling up, when we face the unavoidable need to free up space (at least partially) for storing new entries awaiting commit to the cache memory.

I would suggest looking for some answers from https://stackoverflow.com/users/224132/peter-cordes and https://stackoverflow.com/users/149138/beeonrope  for 'auto flush' vs 'flush button'.

@pveentjer I'm all for it! The answers from these gentlemen are the most authoritative for me! If they could clarify this question and, perhaps, if they were willing, improve my answer in some way, I would only be grateful to them, both on my own behalf and on behalf of the entire community! I also deeply appreciate the time and attention you have given me!

Check out the following answer from Peter Cordess: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54876208/size-of-store-buffers-on-intel-hardware-what-exactly-is-a-store-buffer/54880249#54880249 for more info about the store buffer and that is already committing stores to the cache as fast as it can and ordering is done by delaying other tasks. So no flush button.

@pveentjer Yes, thank you very much! I also asked an additional question on this topic, and Peter, huge thanks to him for this, is providing some consultation about it. I actually read that answer just yesterday, and it shed light on many things! Thank you for helping—now I completely understand that my previous understanding was overly simplified, and I was mistaken about many aspects!

I hope now it is clear that you get visibility for free on the X86.

@pveentjer Yes, I didn't take into account that we live in a world of multi-platform systems. When the issue of visibility of changes arises, it might not be limited to x86. In general, as I understand it, the main problem in those specific situations where visibility of changes is "impossible" lies in various reorderings rather than the functioning of the Store Buffer itself.

AFAIK the only source of lack of visibility in Java is the JIT e.g. when it hoists a variable out of the loop. I don't know any modern mainstream ISA that can delay a write indefinitely.

What I understand from ARM and RISC-V is that their microarchitectures, with respect to the ROB and SB, work similarly, so there is in-order allocation, out-of-order execution, and in-order retirement. The X86 needs to provide store-store ordering so stores commit to the cache in order. But ARM and RISC-V have much weaker memory-model, so they can do all kinds of optimizations that can lead to reordering stores. But they all offer visibility guarantees.

@pveentjer In general, there is some inevitable timeout in terms of the time required to reflect the results of a write operation. This is primarily due to cache coherence across different processor cores, which aligns with the paradigm of eventual consistency. We cannot know the exact moment when the changes will become visible, but we can be certain that they will be committed eventually.

@pveentjer It turns out that the problem is somewhat exaggerated. Or rather, it would be more accurate to say that while the issue potentially exists, its nature is often misunderstood. People tend to blame the internal architecture of modern processors, pointing to buffers, but the root cause, as you have correctly noted, seems to lie in potential reordering, which, importantly, happens at the level of the JIT compiler.

Low-Level Implementation of volatile: Bytecode and Machine Instructions
This article represents the final piece of a broader exploration into the volatile modifier in Java. In Part 1, we examined the origins and semantics of volatile, providing a foundational understanding of its behavior. Part 2 focused on addressing misconceptions and delving into memory structures.
Now, in this conclusive installment, we will analyze the low-level implementation details, including machine-level instructions and processor-specific mechanisms, rounding out the complete picture of volatile in Java. Let’s dive in.

Exploring the Bytecode for volatile Fields
One common assumption among developers is that the volatile modifier in Java introduces specialized bytecode instructions to enforce its semantics. Let’s examine this hypothesis with a straightforward experiment.
Experimental Setup
I created a simple Java file named VolatileTest.java containing the following code:
public class VolatileTest {
    private volatile long someField;
}

Here, a single private field is declared as volatile. To investigate the bytecode, I compiled the file using the Java compiler (javac) from the Oracle OpenJDK JDK 1.8.0_431 (x86) distribution and then disassembled the resulting .class file with the javap utility, using the -v and -p flags for detailed output, including private members.
Comparing Results
I performed two compilations: one with the volatile modifier and one without it. Below are the relevant excerpts of the bytecode for the someField variable:
With volatile:
  private volatile long someField;
    descriptor: J
    flags: ACC_PRIVATE, ACC_VOLATILE

Without volatile:
  private long someField;
    descriptor: J
    flags: ACC_PRIVATE

The only difference is in the flags field. The volatile modifier adds the ACC_VOLATILE flag to the field’s metadata. No additional bytecode instructions are generated.
Hexadecimal Analysis
To explore further, I examined the compiled .class files using a hex editor (ImHex Hex Editor). The binary contents of the two files were nearly identical, differing only in the value of a single byte in the access_flags field, which encodes the modifiers for each field.
For the someField variable:

With volatile: 0x0042
Without volatile: 0x0002

The difference is due to the bitmask for ACC_VOLATILE, defined as 0x0040. This demonstrates that the presence of the volatile modifier merely toggles the appropriate flag in the access_flags field.
Modifiers and Flags
The access_flags field is a 16-bit value that encodes various field-level modifiers. Here’s a summary of relevant flags:



Modifier
Bit Value
Description




ACC_PUBLIC
0x0001
Field is public.


ACC_PRIVATE
0x0002
Field is private.


ACC_PROTECTED
0x0004
Field is protected.


ACC_STATIC
0x0008
Field is static.


ACC_FINAL
0x0010
Field is final.


ACC_VOLATILE
0x0040
Field is volatile.


ACC_TRANSIENT
0x0080
Field is transient.


ACC_SYNTHETIC
0x1000
Field is compiler-generated.


ACC_ENUM
0x4000
Field is part of an enum.



Implications
The volatile keyword’s presence in the bytecode is entirely represented by the ACC_VOLATILE flag. This flag is a single bit in the access_flags field. This minimal change emphasizes that there is no "magic" at the bytecode level—the entire behavior of volatile is represented by this single bit. The JVM uses this information to enforce the necessary semantics, without any additional complexity or hidden mechanisms.

x86 Processors and JVM Compatibility
Before diving into the low-level machine implementation of volatile, it is essential to understand which x86 processors this discussion pertains to and how these processors are compatible with the JVM.
Early JVM and x86 Support
When Java was first released, official support was limited to 32-bit architectures, as the JVM itself—known as the Classic VM from Sun Microsystems—was initially 32-bit. Early Java did not distinguish between editions like SE, EE, or ME; this differentiation began with Java 1.2. Consequently, the first supported x86 processors were those in the Intel 80386 family, as they were the earliest 32-bit processors in the architecture.
Intel 80386 processors, though already considered outdated at the time of Java's debut, were supported by operating systems that natively ran Java, such as Windows NT 3.51, Windows 95, and Solaris x86. These operating systems ensured compatibility with the x86 architecture and the early JVM.
Compatibility with Older x86 Processors
Interestingly, even processors as old as the Intel 8086, the first in the x86 family, could run certain versions of the JVM, albeit with significant limitations. This was made possible through the development of Java Platform, Micro Edition (Java ME), which offered a pared-down version of Java SE. Sun Microsystems developed a specialized virtual machine called K Virtual Machine (KVM) for these constrained environments. KVM required minimal resources, with some implementations running on devices with as little as 128 kilobytes of memory.
KVM's compatibility extended to both 16-bit and 32-bit processors, including those from the x86 family. According to the Oracle documentation in "J2ME Building Blocks for Mobile Devices," KVM was suitable for devices with minimal computational power:

"These devices typically contain 16- or 32-bit processors and a
minimum total memory footprint of approximately 128 kilobytes."

Additionally, it was noted that KVM could work efficiently on CISC architectures such as x86:

"KVM is suitable for 16/32-bit RISC/CISC microprocessors with a total
memory budget of no more than a few hundred kilobytes (potentially
less than 128 kilobytes)."

Furthermore, KVM could run on native software stacks, such as RTOS (Real-Time Operating Systems), enabling dynamic and secure Java execution. For example:

"The actual role of a KVM in target devices can vary significantly. In
some implementations, the KVM is used on top of an existing native
software stack to give the device the ability to download and run
dynamic, interactive, secure Java content on the device."

Alternatively, KVM could function as a standalone low-level system software layer:

"In other implementations, the KVM is used at a lower level to also
implement the lower-level system software and applications of the
device in the Java programming language."

This flexibility ensured that even early x86 processors, often embedded in devices with constrained resources, could leverage Java technologies. For instance, the Intel 80186 processor was widely used in embedded systems running RTOS and supported multitasking through software mechanisms like timer interrupts and cooperative multitasking.
Another example is the experimental implementation of the JVM for MS-DOS systems, such as the KaffePC Java VM. While this version of the JVM allowed for some level of Java execution, it excluded multithreading due to the strict single-tasking nature of MS-DOS. The absence of native multithreading in such environments highlights how certain Java features, including the guarantees provided by volatile, were often simplified, significantly modified, or omitted entirely. Despite this, as we shall see, the principles underlying volatile likely remained consistent with broader architectural concepts, ensuring applicability across diverse processor environments.
Implications for volatile
While volatile semantics were often simplified or omitted in these constrained environments, the core principles likely remained consistent with modern implementations. As our exploration will show, the fundamental ideas behind volatile behavior are deeply rooted in universal architectural concepts, making them applicable across diverse x86 processors.

Low-Level Solution to Reordering and Store Buffer Commit Issues
Finally, let’s delve into how volatile operations are implemented at the machine level. To illustrate this, we’ll examine a simple example where a volatile field is assigned a value. To simplify the experiment, we’ll declare the field as static (this does not influence the outcome).
public class VolatileTest {
    private static volatile long someField;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        someField = 5;
    }
}

This code was executed with the following JVM options:
-server -Xcomp -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+PrintAssembly -XX:CompileCommand=compileonly,VolatileTest.main
Experimental Setup and Execution Context
The test environment includes a dynamically linked hsdis library, enabling runtime disassembly of JIT-compiled code. The -Xcomp option forces the JVM to compile all code immediately, bypassing interpretation and allowing us to directly analyze the final machine instructions. The experiment was conducted on a 32-bit JDK 1.8, but identical results were observed across other versions and vendors of the HotSpot VM.
Here is the key assembly instruction generated for the putstatic operation targeting the volatile field:
0x026e3592: lock addl $0, (%esp)  ;*putstatic someField
                                  ; - VolatileTest::main@3 (line 5)

This instruction reveals the underlying mechanism for enforcing the volatile semantics during writes. Let’s dissect this line and understand its components.
Breaking Down the LOCK Prefix
The LOCK prefix plays a crucial role in ensuring atomicity and enforcing a memory barrier. However, since LOCK is a prefix and not an instruction by itself, it must be paired with another operation. Here, it is combined with the addl instruction, which performs an addition.
Why Use addl with LOCK?

Neutral Operation: The addl instruction adds 0 to the value at the memory address stored in %esp. Adding 0 ensures that the operation does not alter the memory's actual contents, making it a non-disruptive and lightweight operation.
Pointer to the Stack: %esp points to the top of the thread's stack, which is local to the thread and isolated from others. This ensures the operation is thread-safe and does not impact other threads or system-wide resources.
Minimal Overhead: The combination of LOCK with a no-op arithmetic operation introduces minimal performance overhead while triggering the required side effects.

Key Properties of the Stack and %esp
The %esp register (or %rsp in 64-bit systems) serves as the stack pointer, dynamically pointing to the top of the local execution stack. Since the stack is strictly local to each thread, its memory addresses are unique across threads, ensuring isolation.
The use of %esp in this context is particularly advantageous:

Isolation: Stack memory is inherently private to a thread, preventing cross-thread interference.
Dynamic Adaptation: The stack pointer updates automatically as the stack grows or shrinks, simplifying memory management.
Safety: The use of the stack pointer guarantees that the memory being "locked" is not shared, reducing contention risks.

Achieving the volatile Semantics
The LOCK prefix ensures:

Atomicity: No other thread or processor can access the specified memory region until the operation completes.
Memory Barrier Semantics: By default, the LOCK prefix enforces strong memory ordering guarantees, ensuring specific instruction sequences cannot be reordered across the barrier.

However, the mechanism does not enforce a complete draining of the store buffer in all cases. Only the stores that precede the barrier in program order (PO) are guaranteed to be committed to the coherent cache (L1d). This means the draining process is partial: it applies only to the stores that must be visible to subsequent operations as mandated by the memory model. Stores prepared for later commits (but not preceding the barrier) remain in the buffer until their turn in PO arrives.
This nuanced behavior explains why the LOCK prefix does not block all instructions. For example:

Loads and other lock-prefixed instructions* are delayed until older stores (relative to PO) are drained from the store buffer.
Independent instructions (such as computations or stores not requiring immediate commitment) can proceed without delay unless microarchitectural constraints dictate otherwise.

In summary, the LOCK prefix provides targeted control over memory ordering and visibility, ensuring:

Preceding writes are committed to the cache before subsequent loads.
Strict adherence to program order for store-store and store-load sequences.

This mechanism helps address issues related to reordering and store buffer visibility but operates selectively, without enforcing a complete halt on all subsequent operations.
A Note on Read Operations
Interestingly, no memory barrier is required for volatile reads on x86 architectures. The x86 memory model inherently prohibits Load-Load reorderings, which are the only type of reordering that volatile semantics would otherwise prevent for reads. Thus, the hardware guarantees are sufficient without additional instructions.

Atomicity of Writes and Reads in volatile Fields
Now, let us delve into the most intriguing aspect: ensuring atomicity for writes and reads of volatile fields. For 64-bit JVMs, this issue is less critical since operations, even on 64-bit types like long and double, are inherently atomic. Nonetheless, examining how write operations are typically implemented in machine instructions can provide deeper insights.
Code Example
For simplicity, consider the following code:
public class VolatileTest {
    private static volatile long someField;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        someField = 10;
    }
}

Assembly Analysis of Write Operations
Here’s the generated machine code corresponding to the write operation:
0x0000019f2dc6efdb: movabsq       $0x76aea4020, %rsi
                                            ;   {oop(a 'java/lang/Class' = 'VolatileTest')}
0x0000019f2dc6efe5: movabsq       $0xa, %rdi
0x0000019f2dc6efef: movq          %rdi, 0x20(%rsp)
0x0000019f2dc6eff4: vmovsd        0x20(%rsp), %xmm0
0x0000019f2dc6effa: vmovsd        %xmm0, 0x68(%rsi)
0x0000019f2dc6efff: lock addl     $0, (%rsp)  ;*putstatic someField
                                            ; - VolatileTest::main@3 (line 5)

At first glance, the abundance of machine instructions directly interacting with registers might seem unnecessarily complex. However, this approach reflects specific architectural constraints and optimizations. Let us dissect these instructions step by step:
Detailed Breakdown of Instructions

movabsq $0x76aea4020, %rsi
This instruction loads the absolute address (interpreted as a 64-bit numerical value) into the general-purpose register %rsi. From the comment, we see this address points to the class metadata object (java/lang/Class) containing information about the class and its static members. Since our volatile field is static, its address is calculated relative to this metadata object.

This approach ensures uniform handling of positive and negative 64-bit values due to the two's complement representation. While this may not seem critical here, it establishes a consistent method for managing both signed and unsigned integers.


movabsq $0xa, %rdi
Here, the immediate value 0xa (hexadecimal representation of 10) is loaded into the %rdi register. Since direct 64-bit memory writes using immediate values are prohibited in x86-64, this intermediate step is necessary.

movq %rdi, 0x20(%rsp)
The value from %rdi is then stored on the stack at an offset of 0x20 from the current stack pointer %rsp. This transfer is required because subsequent instructions will operate on SIMD registers, which cannot directly access general-purpose registers.

vmovsd 0x20(%rsp), %xmm0
This instruction moves the value from the stack into the SIMD register %xmm0. Although designed for floating-point operations, it efficiently handles 64-bit bitwise representations. The apparent redundancy here (loading and storing via the stack) is a trade-off for leveraging AVX optimizations, which can boost performance on modern microarchitectures like Sandy Bridge.

vmovsd %xmm0, 0x68(%rsi)
The value in %xmm0 is stored in memory at the address calculated relative to %rsi (0x68 offset). This represents the actual write operation to the volatile field.

lock addl $0, (%rsp)
The lock prefix ensures atomicity by locking the cache line corresponding to the specified memory address during execution. While addl $0 appears redundant, it serves as a lightweight no-op to enforce a full memory barrier, preventing reordering and ensuring visibility across threads.


Multiple Writes and Memory Barriers
Consider the following extended code:
public class VolatileTest {
    private static volatile long someField;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        someField = 10;
        someField = 11;
        someField = 12;
    }
}

For this sequence, the compiler inserts a memory barrier after each write:
0x0000029ebe499bdb: movabsq       $0x76aea4070, %rsi
                                            ;   {oop(a 'java/lang/Class' = 'VolatileTest')}
0x0000029ebe499be5: movabsq       $0xa, %rdi
0x0000029ebe499bef: movq          %rdi, 0x20(%rsp)
0x0000029ebe499bf4: vmovsd        0x20(%rsp), %xmm0
0x0000029ebe499bfa: vmovsd        %xmm0, 0x68(%rsi)
0x0000029ebe499bff: lock addl     $0, (%rsp)  ;*putstatic someField
                                            ; - VolatileTest::main@3 (line 5)

0x0000029ebe499c04: movabsq       $0xb, %rdi
0x0000029ebe499c0e: movq          %rdi, 0x28(%rsp)
0x0000029ebe499c13: vmovsd        0x28(%rsp), %xmm0
0x0000029ebe499c19: vmovsd        %xmm0, 0x68(%rsi)
0x0000029ebe499c1e: lock addl     $0, (%rsp)  ;*putstatic someField
                                            ; - VolatileTest::main@9 (line 6)

0x0000029ebe499c23: movabsq       $0xc, %rdi
0x0000029ebe499c2d: movq          %rdi, 0x30(%rsp)
0x0000029ebe499c32: vmovsd        0x30(%rsp), %xmm0
0x0000029ebe499c38: vmovsd        %xmm0, 0x68(%rsi)
0x0000029ebe499c3d: lock addl     $0, (%rsp)  ;*putstatic someField
                                            ; - VolatileTest::main@15 (line 7)

Observations

The lock addl instruction follows each write, ensuring proper visibility and preventing reordering.
These barriers are mandatory and cannot be optimized away by the compiler due to the strict semantics of volatile.

In summary, the intricate sequence of operations underscores the JVM’s efforts to balance atomicity, performance, and compliance with the Java Memory Model.

For 32-Bit Systems: A Unique Challenge
When running the example code on a 32-bit JVM, the behavior differs significantly due to hardware constraints inherent to 32-bit architectures. Let’s dissect the observed assembly code:
0x02e837f0: movl        $0x2f62f848, %esi
                                        ;   {oop(a 'java/lang/Class' = 'VolatileTest')}
0x02e837f5: movl        $0xa, %edi
0x02e837fa: movl        $0, %ebx
0x02e837ff: movl        %edi, 0x10(%esp)
0x02e83803: movl        %ebx, 0x14(%esp)
0x02e83807: vmovsd      0x10(%esp), %xmm0
0x02e8380d: vmovsd      %xmm0, 0x58(%esi)
0x02e83812: lock addl   $0, (%esp)  ;*putstatic someField
                                        ; - VolatileTest::main@3 (line 5)

Register Constraints in 32-Bit Systems
Unlike their 64-bit counterparts, 32-bit general-purpose registers such as %esi and %edi lack the capacity to directly handle 64-bit values. As a result, long values in 32-bit environments are processed in two separate parts: the lower 32 bits ($0xa in this case) and the upper 32 bits ($0). Each part is loaded into a separate 32-bit register and later combined for further processing. This limitation inherently increases the complexity of ensuring atomic operations.
Atomicity Using SIMD Registers
Despite the constraints of 32-bit general-purpose registers, SIMD registers such as %xmm0 offer a workaround. The vmovsd instruction is used to load the full 64-bit value into %xmm0 atomically. The two halves of the long value, previously placed on the stack at offsets 0x10(%esp) and 0x14(%esp), are accessed as a unified 64-bit value during this operation. This highlights the JVM’s efficiency in leveraging modern instruction sets like AVX for compatibility and performance in older architectures.
For 32-Bit Systems: A More Intriguing Case
Let’s delve into the behavior of the same example but run on a 32-bit JVM. Below is the assembly output generated during execution:
0x02e837f0: movl        $0x2f62f848, %esi
                                    ;   {oop(a 'java/lang/Class' = 'VolatileTest')}
0x02e837f5: movl        $0xa, %edi
0x02e837fa: movl        $0, %ebx
0x02e837ff: movl        %edi, 0x10(%esp)
0x02e83803: movl        %ebx, 0x14(%esp)
0x02e83807: vmovsd      0x10(%esp), %xmm0
0x02e8380d: vmovsd      %xmm0, 0x58(%esi)
0x02e83812: lock addl   $0, (%esp)  ;*putstatic someField
                                    ; - VolatileTest::main@3 (line 5)

Here we see a similar unified approach to the 64-bit systems but driven more by necessity. In 32-bit systems, the absence of 64-bit general-purpose registers means the theoretical capabilities are significantly reduced.
Why Use LOCK Selectively?
In 32-bit systems, reads and writes are performed in two instructions rather than one. This inherently breaks atomicity, even with the LOCK prefix. While it might seem logical to rely on LOCK with its bus-locking capabilities, it is often avoided in such scenarios whenever possible due to its substantial performance impact.
To maintain a priority for non-blocking mechanisms, developers often rely on SIMD instructions, such as those involving XMM registers. In our example, the vmovsd instruction is used, which loads the values $0xa and $0 (representing the lower and upper 32-bit halves of the 64-bit long value) into two different 32-bit registers. These are then stored sequentially on the stack and combined atomically using vmovsd.
Simulating the Absence of AVX
What happens if the processor lacks AVX support? By disabling AVX explicitly (-XX:UseAVX=0), we simulate an environment without AVX functionality. The resulting changes in the assembly are:
0x02da3507: movsd       0x10(%esp), %xmm0 
0x02da350d: movsd       %xmm0, 0x58(%esi)

This highlights that the approach remains fundamentally the same. However, the vmovsd instruction is replaced with the older movsd from the SSE instruction set. While movsd lacks the performance enhancements of AVX and operates as a dual-operand instruction, it serves the same purpose effectively when AVX is unavailable.
When SSE is Unavailable
If SSE support is also disabled (-XX:UseSSE=0), the fallback mechanism relies on the Floating Point Unit (FPU):
0x02bc2449: fildll      0x10(%esp)
0x02bc244d: fistpll     0x58(%esi)

Here, the fildll and fistpll instructions load and store the value directly to and from the FPU stack, bypassing the need for SIMD registers. Unlike typical FPU operations involving 80-bit extended precision, these instructions ensure the value remains a raw 64-bit integer, avoiding unnecessary conversions.
The Challenge of Systems Without an FPU
For processors such as the Intel 80486SX or 80386 without integrated coprocessors, the situation becomes even more challenging. These processors lack native instructions like CMPXCHG8B (introduced in the Intel Pentium series) and 64-bit atomicity mechanisms. In such cases, ensuring atomicity requires software-based solutions, such as OS-level mutex locks, which are significantly heavier and less efficient.
Analyzing Reads from Volatile Fields
Finally, let’s examine the behavior during a read operation, such as when retrieving a value for display. The following assembly demonstrates the process:
0x02e62346: fildll      0x58(%ecx)
0x02e62349: fistpll     0x18(%esp)  ;*getstatic someField
                                    ; - VolatileTest::main@9 (line 7)

0x02e6234d: movl        0x18(%esp), %edi
0x02e62351: movl        0x1c(%esp), %ecx
0x02e62355: movl        %edi, (%esp)
0x02e62358: movl        %ecx, 4(%esp)
0x02e6235c: movl        %esi, %ecx  ;*invokevirtual println
                                    ; - VolatileTest::main@12 (line 7)

The read operation essentially mirrors the write process but in reverse. The value is loaded from memory (e.g., 0x58(%ecx)) into ST0, then safely written to the stack. Since the stack is inherently thread-local, this intermediate step ensures that any further operations on the value are thread-safe.

Test Environment Details
All experiments and observations in this article were conducted using the following hardware and software configuration:
Operating System

Edition: Windows 10 Enterprise
Version: 22H2
OS Build: 19045.5198

Processor

Model: Intel® Core™ i7-2960XM CPU @ 2.70 GHz
Architecture: x86-64

Java Development Kit (JDK)
Two versions of Oracle JDK 1.8.0_431 were used during the experiments:

64-bit JDK:

Java HotSpot™ 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.431-b10, mixed mode).


32-bit JDK:

Java HotSpot™ Client VM (build 25.431-b10, mixed mode, sharing).



JVM Settings
The following JVM options were applied:

-server -Xcomp -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+PrintAssembly -XX:CompileCommand=compileonly,VolatileTest.main

Tools

hsdis library: A dynamically linked disassembly library for analyzing machine code generated by the JIT compiler. The assembly code presented in this article follows the AT&T syntax, commonly used in Unix-like environments.
javap utility: Used for bytecode analysis with the -v -p flags.


Conclusion and Acknowledgment
This comprehensive exploration highlights the JVM's remarkable adaptability in enforcing volatile semantics across a range of architectures and processor capabilities. From AVX and SSE to FPU-based fallbacks, each approach balances performance, hardware limitations, and atomicity.
Thank you for accompanying me on this deep dive into volatile. This analysis has answered many questions and broadened my understanding of low-level JVM implementations. I hope it has been equally insightful for you!

"This mechanism elegantly addresses the potential issues of reordering and store buffer commits, ensuring that all preceding writes are visible before any subsequent operations."
A lock-prefixed instruction only needs to delay loads (and other lock-prefixed instructions) that come later in the program order until the store buffer is drained. Other instructions are not blocked (unless there is some weird micro-architecture-specific behavior).

"For this sequence, the compiler inserts a memory barrier after each write" In theory that isn't needed. On X86 only an older store and a newer load to a different address can be reordered. But stores can't be reordered and hence there is no need to have a fence between stores. So apparently the compiler did a shitty job. Was the JIT properly heated?

About volatile loads not needing a fence on X86; this was a choice. The only fence needed on X86 is a [StoreLoad]. So compiler writers can optimize for the reading side (so a [StoreLoad] before a read) or optimize for the writing side by adding a [StoreLoad] after the write. Since typically loads happen more frequently than writes, the writing side is victimized. https://shipilev.net/blog/2014/on-the-fence-with-dependencies/

@pveentjer
Yes, I completely agree regarding volatile field loads. A barrier isn’t needed there due to the memory model. In other architectures, such as ARM, this might theoretically make sense, but not in x86. The absence of redundant and, in this case, clearly unnecessary instructions is an optimization element. As for the semantics of LOCK, I’ve made some changes to my answer. Perhaps I’m mistaken again, but nevertheless, I’m doing my best to improve my response, and more importantly, my understanding of all these concepts.

@pveentjer As for the JIT compiler and warming up, it’s hard for me to say with 100% certainty. It’s entirely possible that a different compilation result could be achieved. However, in all the test cases I personally checked, I observed this exact behavior. Not once in the disassembled listing did I encounter alternative approaches. It’s possible that the behavior may indeed vary, but I’ve only demonstrated one of the possible outcomes that I was able to achieve in practice through testing.

I'm pretty sure the JIT will get rid of superfluous fences with a sequence of volatile stores when properly warmed up. A JMH test should show.

@pveentjer The question is different. It may well remove them, but how then will the visibility guarantee for new writes be ensured at the hardware level? After all, instructions with the LOCK prefix at least forced the system to wait for writes to be committed to the cache before proceeding further.

The JMM visibility guarantee on the X86 you get for free since the store buffer will be drained automatically. So stores will leave the store buffer ASAP. You don't need any fences for that.
With the flush-button model it becomes problematic; imagine you have 1 store and than tons of other operations. Now the store could end up as not visible since the store buffer isn't full and there is no operation triggering a flush. Another good argument why the flush button model is broken.

@pveentjer This sounds extremely constructive. But if that's the case, why do we even need LOCK? Is it exclusively for memory barrier semantics and nothing else? Does visibility have nothing to do with it?

The key problem on the X86, is that due to the store buffer, an older store can be reordered with a newer load to a different address. And this is one of the things a lock prefixed instruction (or an mfence) prevents. Due to store buffers already being drained ASAP, X86 will provide visibility for free; only ordering needs to have a bit of help.

In the JMM, all correctly synchronized programs need to have sequential consistent executions. So no reordering is allowed and that is why we need to prevent the reordering of an older store with a newer load to a different address (which is what an mfence or lock prefixed instruction will help with).

And lock prefixed instructions are also very useful for composite atomic operations (since plain loads/stores are already guaranteed to be atomic if naturally aligned). So things like a compare and swap or increment.

@pveentjer Why then is a pure MFENCE instruction not used? What do you think? It would reduce confusion. I once read that the LOCK prefix at the opcode level is supposedly more optimized. Is this true, and is this the reason why it is used in practice instead of a pure SFENCE or MFENCE in the x86 architecture?

Performance. Lock prefixed instructions are appearently faster than an MFENCE. Benchmarking was done by David Dice 2 decades ago if I remember correctly that shows that MFENCE was slower. SFENCE has little value for the JMM since that is for weakly ordered stores which are not part of the JMM. On the X86 you already get the guarantee that stores can't be reordered because stores will commit to the L1d in program order.

Keep in mind that on the X86, every plain store has release semantics (so will prevent earlier loads/stores to be reordered with that store). And every load has acquire semantics (so will prevent later loads/stores to be reordered with that load). So plain stores on the X86 are guaranteed to be issued to the coherent cache in program order.

@pveentjer Yes, indeed, I found Dave's post on this topic in the Internet Archive, which he wrote back in 2009. The primary motivation was indeed performance, specifically with the then-new processors from AMD. The lock-prefixed instruction demonstrated better performance with them. However, it is worth noting that MFENCE was used earlier, and for older processors, this choice still remains valid even within the x86 architecture.

Not really answering your question, because I'm not going to say anything about x86 architecture, but as rzwitserloot said, you really should not worry about the underlying architecture when you write Java code.

So anyway, according to the rules in the JLS,
If you remove volatile from the declaration of v, then the assert in this program could fail. With volatile, it cannot fail.
class VTest {
    static int x = 0;
    static volatile int v = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread t = new Thread(() -> {
            x = 7;
            v = 5;
        });
        t.start();
        int local_v = v;
        int local_x = x;
        if (local_v == 5) {
            assert local_x == 7;
    }
}

Making v volatile guarantees that everything the new thread did before it assigned v=5 will be visible to the main thread after the main thread reads v *IF* the main thread sees the 5 that the new thread wrote.
There is no guarantee that the main thread will see v==5, but if it does see v==5, then it must also see x==7.

This isn't complete. volatile does a little more than just guarantee observability of sequencing. But it is correct. I cannot fathom a proper answer to this question that does not contain the word sequence "Happens Before" at least once.... but then again I mostly cannot fathom a proper answer to this question other than copy/pasting the entire JMM which doesn't seem appropriate either. What the heck, upvoted :)

Thank you very much! I understand that in this way we are excluding instruction reordering that could violate the happens-before relationship. On x86 architecture, this can be implemented in various ways, and if I'm not mistaken, the implementation has indeed changed and will directly depend on the code generated at the JVM level. This can depend on the JDK version and the vendor. Again, as far as I understand, the cache is not the issue here.

It seems to me that my main question revolves around this, and I chose the x86 architecture as the most understandable for myself and wanted to either refute or confirm these aspects using it as an example.

@rzwitserloot Yes, dear friend, I completely agree with you here! I would say that volatile is entirely about happens-before (at least in my own understanding and perception). Everything else follows as a consequence or a kind of "side effect."

@Lexoid, Re, "volatile is entirely about happens-before..." The example that I constructed for my "answer," above is entirely meant to illustrate a consequence of "happens before." To wit: The assignment x=7 happens before the assignment v=5 in the second thread because those operations must happen in program order. And, the volatile type qualifier carries that relationship over to the main thread. If the main thread is able to see that the assignment v=5 happened at all, then it too must see that x=7 happened before.

@SolomonSlow I agree that reasoning on any topic, including implementation, can and should start from these guarantees. They are fundamental, and the very idea of introducing happens-before was to provide a conceptual foundation for both programmers and JVM developers. When I allowed myself to delve into implementation details, I realized that one must think in terms of what needs to be done at a low level to ensure that these guarantees hold. Ultimately, everything comes down to this.

@SolomonSlow Different architectures and even different JVMs might employ their own technical solutions, but they must all necessarily implement the happens-before principle.

A Comprehensive Dive Into volatile in Java: From Its Origins to Modern Semantics
Dear readers,
The Stack Overflow community has been instrumental in guiding me toward understanding the volatile modifier in Java. However, as I delved deeper into this topic, I realized the need to compile my thoughts into a comprehensive explanation that would benefit not only myself but also others seeking clarity on this intricate concept. This will be a multi-part exploration, as the depth of the subject demands it. While I might err in certain details, I aim to provide a detailed and accurate explanation. Let’s begin!

Part 1: volatile in Java — A Historical Perspective
Among all Java modifiers, volatile is perhaps the most challenging to fully understand. Unlike other modifiers, its guarantees have evolved significantly across different versions of the Java platform. To grasp its semantics, we must first delve into its origins and initial purpose.
The Origins of volatile
The volatile modifier has been part of Java since its very first release, reflecting the language’s ambition to dominate high-performance server-side applications. Multithreading support was fundamental to this vision, and Java borrowed heavily from languages like C++ to introduce essential synchronization primitives. volatile was one such primitive, designed to serve as a lightweight mechanism for managing visibility between threads.
Early Guarantees of volatile
In its initial iterations, volatile offered two main guarantees:

Visibility: Updates made to a volatile variable by one thread would eventually become visible to other threads. This ensures that no thread continues to operate indefinitely on stale data, as changes are reconciled with the main memory as quickly as feasible. Importantly, this does not imply immediate visibility but rather guarantees eventual consistency.
Atomicity of Simple Load and Store Operations:
For basic read and write operations, including those involving 64-bit types such as long and double, volatile ensured atomicity. However, compound operations (e.g., increment, decrement) remained non-atomic due to their multi-step nature (read-modify-write).

These guarantees are explicitly documented in the earliest edition of the Java Language Specification (JLS), which can still be accessed here. Let’s analyze two critical excerpts:
Visibility Guarantee
From Section 8.3.1.4 volatile Fields:

"Java provides a second mechanism that is more convenient for some purposes: a field may be declared volatile, in which case a thread
must reconcile its working copy of the field with the master copy
every time it accesses the variable. Moreover, operations on the
master copies of one or more volatile variables on behalf of a thread
are performed by the main memory in exactly the order that the thread
requested."

This statement underscores that volatile ensures visibility by requiring threads to reconcile their working copies with the main memory whenever they interact with a volatile variable.
Atomicity for long and double
From Section 17.4 Nonatomic Treatment of double and long:

"If a double or long variable is not declared volatile, then for the purposes of load, store, read, and write actions they are treated as
if they were two variables of 32 bits each."

In contrast, declaring a long or double as volatile ensures atomicity for basic load and store operations.

Challenges in Early Java Memory Models
Despite these guarantees, significant issues emerged due to the lack of a defined Java Memory Model (JMM). The specification imposed no strict constraints on memory interactions, leaving Java’s memory model largely undefined. As a result, Java's early memory model could be classified as weak, allowing for extensive reordering of read and write operations across different levels.
Sources of Reordering
Reordering could occur at three primary levels, each contributing to potential inconsistencies in multithreaded programs:

Bytecode Compiler (javac): While the bytecode compiler generally preserved the logical flow of a program, it occasionally performed minor optimizations. These optimizations might reorder operations in limited cases, although javac was relatively conservative compared to other sources of reordering. Its primary goal was to preserve the developer’s intent while generating efficient bytecode.

Just-In-Time (JIT) Compiler: The JIT compiler, introduced in JDK 1.1, became a significant source of reordering. Its purpose is to maximize runtime performance, often by aggressively optimizing code execution. Operating under the principle, “Anything not explicitly forbidden is permitted,” the JIT compiler dynamically analyzes code and reorders instructions to improve efficiency.
Several factors influence JIT behavior:

JVM flags: Options such as -XX:+AggressiveOpts or tuning garbage collection can indirectly affect JIT optimizations.
Workload: The JIT compiler may optimize code differently depending on runtime conditions, such as the frequency of method calls or contention on shared resources.
Implementation: The behavior can vary across JIT compilers (e.g., C1 for client-side performance and C2 for server-side optimizations) and JVM versions.  (In early versions of the HotSpot JVM, server vs. client VMs really did optimize differently.  That hasn't been the case for years.)

This runtime adaptability makes it challenging to predict the exact sequence of operations in a multithreaded environment.  Also, relying on a compiler not to do a specific optimization that's allowed on paper is not future-proof against later improvements in JIT compilers.

CPU-Level Reordering: Modern processors utilize instruction-level parallelism and sophisticated caching mechanisms to maximize throughput. These hardware-level optimizations often result in the reordering of independent instructions. For instance:

Out-of-order execution allows the CPU to execute instructions based on the availability of execution units rather than their program order, allowing loads to run early.  (Out-of-order completion of loads is also possible on in-order CPUs with non-blocking caches that do hit-under-miss and miss-under-miss, if they only stall when an instruction tries to read a load result that isn't ready yet.  Memory reordering does still happen on CPUs that begin execution of each instruction in program order.)
The store buffer decouples execution from cache-miss stores, and makes speculative execution of stores possible.  It naturally introduces StoreLoad reordering, and out-of-order commit from it to L1d cache can introduce StoreStore reordering on ISAs which allow that.
Memory subsystems, governed by protocols like MESI to maintain cache coherency, further complicate consistency by deferring visibility of updates across processor cores.  But cache is coherent between cores that run threads of a Java program, and sequential consistency can be recovered with memory barriers that just control the order of a thread's own accesses to cache.
See also How does memory reordering help processors and compilers?

These hardware behaviors add another layer of complexity to reasoning about multithreaded programs.


The interplay between these three levels—bytecode compiler, JIT compiler, and CPU—compounded the challenges of managing memory consistency in early Java.

A Classic Example of Reordering in Early Java
Consider the following program, which illustrates the pitfalls of weak memory models:
public class ReorderingExample { 
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public void T1() {
        x = 1;
        int r1 = y;
    }

    public void T2() {
        y = 1;
        int r2 = x;
    }
}

In this example:

The absence of volatile allows the bytecode compiler, JIT compiler, and CPU to freely reorder operations.
Possible outcomes for r1 and r2 include inconsistent states, such as (0, 0), (1, 0), or (0, 1).

To ensure consistent results in early Java, the only option was to declare both fields as volatile.

Why volatile Prevents Reordering
The JLS explicitly prohibits reordering operations involving volatile variables. From Section 8.3.1.4:

"Operations on the master copies of one or more volatile variables on behalf of a thread are performed by the main memory in exactly the
order that the thread requested."

This rule applies to all volatile variables, even if they are distinct. Therefore, no read or write operation involving a volatile variable can be reordered with another.

The Role of JIT in Reordering
To better understand the challenges of reordering, we need to consider the dynamic nature of the JIT compiler:

Unlike javac, which operates statically, the JIT compiler performs runtime optimizations that vary based on system conditions and workload.
Its guiding principle, “Anything not explicitly forbidden is permitted,” leads to aggressive reordering and optimization.
Predicting JIT behavior is inherently difficult, as it depends on a combination of runtime factors such as thread contention, memory pressure, and JVM-specific implementation details.


A Partial Fix with volatile
Let’s revisit the earlier example with one field declared as volatile:
public class ReorderingExample { 
    private volatile int x; 
    private int y; 

    public void T1() {
        x = 1;
        int r1 = y;
    }

    public void T2() {
        y = 1;
        int r2 = x;
    }
}

Declaring x as volatile guarantees:

Updates to x will become visible to all threads as quickly as possible.
Writes to x cannot be reordered with subsequent reads or writes to x.

However, operations involving y remain unrestricted. To fully eliminate the possibility of reordering, both fields must be declared as volatile.

Part 2: The Introduction of the New Java Memory Model and Its Impact on volatile
A pivotal moment in the evolution of Java’s memory model occurred with the introduction of JSR-133: Java™ Memory Model and Thread Specification Revision. The finalization of JSR-133 coincided with the release of Java 2 Platform Standard Edition 5.0 (J2SE 5.0), codenamed Tiger. This release marked a significant milestone in multithreading capabilities, bringing numerous enhancements to the Java ecosystem.
Key Innovations in J2SE 5.0
The J2SE 5.0 release introduced several groundbreaking features:

The java.util.concurrent library: A suite of tools for parallel programming, developed under the guidance of Doug Lea, which significantly simplified multithreaded application development.
Optimized intrinsic locks: Enhancements to internal locking mechanisms introduced strategies such as Biased Locking and Lightweight Locking (Biased Locking has since been deprecated).
The New Java Memory Model (New JMM): A more robust and formalized memory model that replaced the loosely defined approach of earlier Java versions.

The New JMM addressed long-standing consistency issues and provided a solid foundation for multithreaded programming. While it impacted a variety of synchronization mechanisms, such as synchronized blocks and final fields, the focus here will be on its implications for volatile.

Changes to volatile in the New JMM
The New JMM preserved the original guarantees of volatile—visibility and atomicity for simple load and store operations. However, it introduced additional guarantees, most notably:

Reordering restrictions through the happens-before (hb) relationship: A formalization that defines memory consistency rules.
Clarifications on synchronization semantics: The introduction of release-acquire actions tied to volatile operations.

The Happens-Before Relationship and volatile
The happens-before relationship, introduced in Section 17.4.5 of the JLS, provides the theoretical framework for memory synchronization:

Two actions can be ordered by a happens-before relationship. If one action happens-before another, then the first is visible to and
ordered before the second.

This framework ensures consistency in multithreaded interactions and underpins the new guarantees for volatile. Specifically:

A write to a volatile field happens-before every subsequent read of that field.
If hb(x, y) and hb(y, z), then hb(x, z).

This transitivity is critical for ensuring that changes made by one thread propagate correctly and predictably to other threads.

Practical Implications of the Happens-Before Relationship
Synchronization Mechanisms and Acquire/Release Semantics
The establishment of a happens-before relationship in a multithreaded environment requires the use of synchronization mechanisms with acquire/release semantics:

Release action: Writing to a volatile field.
Acquire action: Reading from the same volatile field.

These actions ensure proper ordering and visibility of changes. For instance:

Thread T1 writes to a volatile variable (release action).
Thread T2 reads from the same volatile variable (acquire action).

Once T2 observes the value written by T1, all prior changes made by T1 (before the volatile write) become visible to T2. However, this relationship is only established when the write operation is fully performed and becomes visible to the entire system.

Eventual Visibility and Propagation Delays
It is crucial to emphasize that happens-before relationships are established at runtime and depend on the propagation of changes across the system. This process is not instantaneous. While modern systems optimize for low latency, synchronization still takes measurable time due to:

Cache coherence protocols: Mechanisms like MESI (and its derivatives) govern the invalidation and propagation of cache lines.
Invalidation queues: When multiple cores attempt to synchronize concurrently, delays can occur if invalidation queues are overloaded.

For example:

When Thread T1 writes to a volatile field, the CPU core needs to get MESI Exclusive ownership of the cache line before it can modify its copy of that line in its L1d cache by committing the store from the store buffer.  It will send out a Read-For-Ownership (RFO), or just an Invalidate if it already has a copy, and wait for a response.  Otherwise we could end up with two cores with conflicting changes to the same cache line, exactly what MESI prevents.
Other cores must invalidate their copies of the cache line to maintain consistency.  But they may send back an acknowledgement of the invalidate request before fully processing it, putting the request in their invalidation queue, so loads might continue to be able to read the old data for a little while longer than you might expect.
After invalidating their own copy of the line, loads by other threads will miss in cache.  They'll have to get a copy by doing a MESI Share request; the writer will downgrade their cache line to Shared and send a copy to core that requested it.  (Or write-back as far as a shared L3 cache so other cores can get it from there.  Modifications to MESI like MESIF and MOESI in real CPUs let them avoid writing back all the way to DRAM when sharing recently-written "dirty" cache lines.)

This propagation process introduces a delay, albeit minimal in most scenarios. However, the visibility of changes depends on the successful propagation of the specific write operation being observed.

Programming Considerations for Volatile Synchronization
The eventual consistency of volatile operations necessitates careful programming practices:

Do not assume instantaneous updates: The propagation of changes between threads, while fast, is not immediate. Code relying on volatile must account for this delay.

Verify expected values explicitly: If a specific value is expected to be written by one thread and read by another, implement logic to check for that value (e.g., a spin-wait loop or condition check). For example:
while (!flag) {
    // Spin-wait until the flag is set to true by another thread
}

This ensures that the desired changes are observed before proceeding.

Avoid assumptions about timing: The exact moment when a happens-before relationship is established cannot be predicted. It depends on runtime factors, including system load and hardware behavior.


A load will either see a store from another thread or not.  Whether that's due to inter-thread latency or just simple timing (the thread doing the store ran later) is normally irrelevant for correctness.  Think about ordering, not timing.

Reordering Restrictions in the New JMM
The New JMM imposes strict constraints on reordering around volatile fields:

Writes Before a volatile Write: Operations preceding a volatile write cannot be reordered to occur after it.
Reads After a volatile Read: Operations following a volatile read cannot be reordered to occur before it.

Additionally:

Store-Store Reordering: Writes to volatile fields cannot be reordered with subsequent writes to non-volatile fields.
Load-Load Reordering: Reads from volatile fields cannot be reordered with subsequent reads from non-volatile fields.

These rules define memory barriers around volatile operations, ensuring predictable behavior and data consistency.

Establishing Happens-Before Relationships in Practice
The critical point for developers to understand is that a happens-before relationship is only established when the observed write operation is completed and visible to the reading thread. This visibility is a runtime phenomenon, not a compile-time guarantee. For instance:

Thread T2 cannot establish a happens-before relationship with a write from Thread T1 until it observes the exact value written by T1.
If multiple writes occur, the reading thread must confirm the presence of the specific write it expects.

This behavior underscores the dynamic nature of happens-before relationships and the importance of designing code to account for eventual consistency. By properly utilizing volatile and other synchronization primitives, developers can ensure correct and consistent behavior in multithreaded programs.

Conclusion
The New Java Memory Model resolved many of the consistency issues inherent in earlier versions of Java. By formalizing the happens-before relationship, it introduced a robust framework for managing multithreaded interactions. While this discussion focused on volatile and its updated semantics, the next step is to explore the hardware-level implementation of these guarantees and how they interact with modern CPU architectures.
Stay tuned for the next section, where we dive deeper into these implementation details!

I made some edits to correct some mis-statements like that MESI caches were a cause of reordering.  Really they just cause cache misses which make CPUs want to reorder locally to still get some work done.  If the parts I expanded are more technical in a CPU-architecture sense than you wanted this answer to be, feel free to simplify and let me know so I can review, or I can try to simplify if you want.

I was under the impression that Java volatile was like C++ atomic with memory_order_seq_cst, that it offers Sequential Consistency for data-race-free programs.  (And multiple Java experts confirm that on Sequential consistency volatile explanation confirms that.)  The ordering restrictions you describe in this answer only amount to acquire/release.  To get seq_cst, you also need to forbid a volatile load from reading cache before previous volatile stores are globally visible.

(And on ISAs like PowerPC that allow IRIW reordering, you also need to forbid that for volatile, as in the link in my previous comment.  Will two atomic writes to different locations in different threads always be seen in the same order by other threads? explains the hardware mechanism for this rare effect in C++ with weaker orders that don't forbid it.)

@PeterCordes
Dear friend,
I am truly delighted that you have improved my answer! I am very pleased with your contributions, and I wholeheartedly support the idea of us collaborating to create a high-quality piece on this topic, if that’s possible. My research turned out to be quite extensive, as I had to figure out many nuances myself. To be honest, I’m a beginner in programming, so many of these things were revelations for me.

@PeterCordes The thing is, I’m still planning to expand my answer to fully address the question I asked six months ago. I envision adding two more parts that will aim to cover the entire semantics of volatile in the Java programming language—from the high-level concepts down to the machine instructions.

@PeterCordes I already have the output from a disassembler at hand, so I’ll try to finish the remaining parts in the coming days. These will include examples of how the JIT compiles machine code to ensure the atomicity of reads and writes, as well as the implementation of visibility guarantees between different threads. I think it could be quite interesting.
Thank you for your attention and support!

Often a beginner perspective is helpful to see what needs explaining, which us veterans have forgotten was once a tricky concept but which we now take for granted.  I'm happy to look over what you've written to make sure it's correct.  I'm not a Java expert, but I know about memory models and assembly language.  I'll probably notice when you edit since I follow active questions in a bunch of tags, but feel free to @ notify me when you have a set of edits complete that you'd like me to review.

Relevant existing Q&As include Is incrementing an int effectively atomic in specific cases? / Atomicity of loads and stores on x86 / Why does a std::atomic store with sequential consistency use XCHG? (volatile store on x86) / Why does C#'s Thread.MemoryBarrier() use "lock or" instead of mfence? (includes some mention of JVMs also doing this).  / C++ How is release-and-acquire achieved on x86 only using MOV?

@PeterCordes
I would also like to confirm that volatile is fully capable of ensuring Sequential Consistency and can indeed be used as a lightweight synchronizer. If there is no need for transactional execution of instructions and no complex operations like read-modify-write are involved, then why not? It can be entirely sufficient in such cases!

@PeterCordes
Thank you so much, I will definitely reach out when I need your input on this question. Once again, thank you for not leaving these matters without your experienced perspective!

@PeterCordes Peter, good day! I’m glad to welcome you! Could you please take a professional look at the second part of my extended response? I’m compelled to reference certain architectural aspects here. If you can add or correct anything, I’m always open to improvements and will be immensely grateful to you!
Please take a look here.

@PeterCordes Additionally, I have completed the final part where I directly addressed the initial question regarding the machine instructions that ensure the necessary semantics. You can find it here. If you have the time and opportunity to review it, I would greatly appreciate it, as it contains many details related to architectural aspects. This work reflects my current understanding and perspective at this stage of my development. Thank you!

I was busy today; I'll have a look probably tomorrow.  Thanks for the update.

@PeterCordes Of course, no problem at all. Take your time, and whenever you have a free moment! I’m immensely grateful!

To nitpick: the initial example is fundamentally flawed because nobody can observe the effects of the reordering, and therefore any reordering is perfectly legal (no matter how much synchronization is added). The JIT could even decide to optimize out the loads.

About the 'eventual consistent'. I would be careful with that; sequential consistency (SC) doesn't require that the real-time order of requests is preserved and SC is a form of strong consistency. Linearizability is SC + real-time order.

volatile -> "Store-Store Reordering": Writes to volatile fields cannot be reordered with subsequent writes to non-volatile fields. A volatile write will order plain stores (and loads) before, it but it will not order any plain loads after it. But keep in mind that you are now entering the territory or fences and fences are not a good replacement for the JMM. E.g. writing to a volatile variable purely for its fencing behavior, is broken. https://shipilev.net/blog/2016/close-encounters-of-jmm-kind/#myth-barriers-are-sane.

"The store buffer .. It naturally introduces StoreLoad reordering, and out-of-order commit from it to L1d cache " The store buffer is a FIFO queue, slots are assigned in program order (PO), the stores can execute out of order, but will retire in order and commit to the coherent cache IN ORDER (on the X86).

The in-order commit to the coherent cache is how the X86 ensures the [StoreStore] ordering (older stores can't be reordered with newer stores).

@pveentjer
I’ve somewhat figured out the store buffer and the FIFO queue. Overall, as for my answer, it’s not as deep as I’d like it to be. I’ve provided a surface-level overview, even though I understand that the topic is much deeper. If I manage to clarify the details in terms of my own understanding of these concepts, I’ll gladly do so! If there are experts in this area willing to help, I openly invite everyone to contribute to the edits. I don’t view this answer as a form of intellectual property.

@pveentjer I fully accept the criticism! The initial example is overly simplified, and the way it’s written can indeed lead to misinterpretations. However, it was intended to describe a situation where we have at least two different execution threads, and observing such a reordering is possible in our scenario. That said, strictly speaking, it’s not guaranteed. On this point, I completely agree with you!

Understanding Misconceptions About volatile in Java: A Comprehensive Analysis
Building on our initial discussion in Part 1, we now transition from high-level semantics to a detailed exploration of the low-level implementation of the volatile keyword in Java. This section aims to clarify its role in memory interactions, busting common misconceptions along the way.
Memory Hierarchy: The Building Blocks
To understand the low-level behavior of volatile, it’s crucial to examine the structure and function of computer memory. Broadly, memory can be categorized into three key areas:

Processor Registers
Processor Cache
Main Memory (RAM)

Let’s explore each of these components and their interactions in greater detail.

Processor Registers: Local and Ultra-Fast Memory
Registers are the fastest memory locations within a CPU, directly embedded in the processing cores and inherently local to the executing processor or core. Their size and configuration are tied to the processor's architecture. For instance, x86-64 processors typically feature 16 general-purpose registers, each capable of storing 64 bits.
Registers play a pivotal role in modern systems, acting as the first point of contact for intermediate calculations and frequently used operands. By ensuring repeated access within registers, such as in iterative operations or loops, they dramatically reduce latency compared to cache or main memory interactions.
Modern processors utilize registers extensively during out-of-order execution. This allows simultaneous processing of instructions by reordering their execution based on operand availability and dependencies. Temporary results are held in registers, ensuring rapid access during speculative execution and improving overall throughput.

Processor Cache: Bridging Speed Gaps Between CPU and Memory
Processor caches mitigate the speed disparity between the CPU's high-frequency operation and the comparatively slower main memory. Modern cache hierarchies rely on static random-access memory (SRAM), offering low latency and high-speed data access. Early processor designs omitted caches, as memory and bus speeds were sufficiently aligned. However, the gap widened in the 1990s, necessitating integrated caches to maintain performance.

Modern Organization: Modern CPUs employ multi-level caches:

L1 Cache: Local to each core; fastest but smallest, often split into instruction (L1i) and data (L1d) caches.
L2 Cache: Larger than L1, still local to cores, serving as a secondary buffer.
L3 Cache: Shared across all cores in most designs. It is often referred to as the last-level cache (LLC) unless a higher cache level, such as L4, exists in the architecture. In such cases, L4 assumes the role of LLC.



Cache Lines and Data Locality
Caches operate with cache lines, typically 64 bytes on x86 processors. Accessing one memory address often fetches adjacent addresses into the cache, optimizing for spatial locality. For example, sequential memory operations, such as iterating over arrays, benefit significantly as related data is preloaded into faster-access memory.
Cache Coherence Protocols and L4 Experimentation
Caches must stay synchronized across cores to prevent stale data. Protocols like MESI (Modified, Exclusive, Shared, Invalid) ensure consistency across multi-threaded environments by defining the state of cached data:

Modified (M): Data in the cache has been updated but not written to main memory.
Exclusive (E): Data is consistent with main memory but not shared with other caches.
Shared (S): Data exists in multiple caches and matches main memory.
Invalid (I): The cache entry is outdated due to modifications elsewhere.

These protocols prevent stale reads and write conflicts. Modern processors, however, often rely on enhanced protocols like MESIF and MOESI, which add additional states (e.g., Forward and Owned) to optimize cache coherence, especially in multi-core and distributed systems.
Additionally, higher cache levels, such as L4 caches, have been experimentally introduced in some architectures. These typically use embedded DRAM (eDRAM) to act as an extended last-level cache (LLC), such as Intel's "Crystal Well" processors. Importantly, the LLC is not always the L3 cache; in systems with L4, it supersedes L3 as the LLC. A notable example includes Intel Xeon designs, where L3 is divided among clusters, and L4 becomes the system-wide shared cache.
These protocols prevent stale reads and write conflicts, integral to multi-threaded operations involving volatile variables.

Main Memory (RAM): The Shared and Slowest Layer
Main memory, or Random Access Memory (RAM), serves as the largest and most shared memory layer across threads and processes. Its primary advantage is size, accommodating vast datasets, but this comes at the cost of higher latencies due to its reliance on Dynamic RAM (DRAM) technology. Accessing RAM incurs delays spanning hundreds of CPU cycles, emphasizing the importance of caches to mitigate performance bottlenecks.
Accessing RAM

Cache Misses: When data isn’t found in any cache level, it must be fetched from RAM, incurring significant latency.
Evictions: Overflowing cache lines result in data being written back to RAM, governed by replacement policies like LRU (Least Recently Used).

Direct memory access (DMA) and memory-mapped I/O can also influence how main memory is used in certain systems, but these typically operate outside the direct purview of application-level multithreading.

Debunking the Myths About volatile
Myth 1: volatile disables caching or forces direct access to RAM
One of the most prevalent misconceptions about the volatile modifier is the belief that it disables the CPU cache or forces the processor to bypass it entirely and work directly with main memory. Let’s clarify this misunderstanding in detail.
Even though early processors like the Intel 80486 allowed disabling caching by setting the Cache Disable (CD) bit in the CR0 register—effectively turning off all levels of caching—this behavior has nothing to do with the way volatile operates. Moreover, while x86 instruction sets include commands like WBINVD (Write Back and Invalidate Cache), INVD (Invalidate Cache), and CLFLUSH (Cache Line Flush), these are primarily low-level mechanisms intended for specialized use cases. Modern processors and their automated cache-coherence protocols (e.g., MESI) handle caching tasks much more efficiently without manual intervention.
Historical Context and Cache Control
Commands like WBINVD and INVD first appeared with the Intel 80486 processors, before MESI became a standard feature in later processor generations. Before the advent of MESI, programmers had to manually manage cache invalidations and flushes to ensure data consistency. However, modern processors manage cache coherence dynamically, rendering manual manipulation not only unnecessary but potentially counterproductive.
Why the Misconception Persists
The confusion likely stems from misunderstandings about modern memory hierarchies, especially the role of store buffers introduced with Intel’s P6 architecture (e.g., Pentium Pro). With out-of-order execution, processors gained the ability to reorder memory operations for improved performance.
For example, a write operation might temporarily remain in the store buffer, awaiting finalization. While the data resides there, it hasn’t yet been committed to the L1 cache or made visible to other processor cores. Automated coherence mechanisms only function once the data is fully committed, and until then, it remains effectively invisible to other threads. This behavior can lead to the perception that volatile bypasses the cache, but in reality, it works within these mechanisms to ensure consistency.
How volatile Influences This
The volatile modifier ensures that writes to a variable are committed promptly and that subsequent reads reflect the latest committed value. However, volatile does not disable the cache; instead, it uses memory barriers to enforce ordering and ensure that data written to the store buffer is visible across threads. This process interacts with the cache like any other operation but with added synchronization guarantees.
By leveraging modern CPU designs and Java’s Memory Model, volatile achieves consistent visibility without requiring manual manipulation of caches or bypassing their functionality.

Myth 2: volatile Limits the Use of Registers
A common claim in online discussions suggests that while volatile does not directly disable the CPU cache, it imposes restrictions on the use of registers. Let's unpack this assertion.
Some proponents argue that benchmarks show slight performance drops when using volatile, leading them to believe that registers are either underutilized or bypassed entirely. The claim often states that without volatile, registers can act as high-speed storage for computations involving shared memory, but once volatile is applied, data is immediately flushed back to memory, bypassing registers.
This idea, however, is fundamentally flawed. Registers are an essential component of processor architecture, used for storing operands and intermediate results. The idea of avoiding or "clearing" registers during volatile operations conflicts with how processors function. Results of calculations may still reside in registers even after a volatile write; the memory barriers introduced by volatile ensure timely data visibility without disrupting typical register usage.
Disassembly of code involving volatile demonstrates no significant difference in register usage compared to non-volatile code. Registers continue to be used actively, highlighting that volatile does not introduce unnecessary register-related overhead. Instead, the performance impact is due to memory barriers forcing writes to propagate from store buffers to cache and ensuring consistent visibility across threads.
In summary, volatile does not restrict the use of registers, and observed performance differences are attributable to synchronization mechanisms rather than register behavior.

Myth 3: volatile Is Unnecessary in Single-Processor Systems
It might seem logical to assume that volatile is irrelevant in single-processor systems since all threads share the same cache. However, there are several nuances to consider.
Hyper-Threading and Store-to-Load Forwarding
Take the legendary Intel Pentium 4 as an example. With the advent of Hyper-Threading (HT), a single physical core could host multiple hardware threads. In such setups, the store buffer—a temporary area for uncommitted writes—is split between threads. This means each hardware thread interacts with its isolated store buffer region, even though they share the same L1 cache.
A feature called Store-to-Load Forwarding (STLF) allows a thread to access data directly from its store buffer, even if the value hasn’t been committed to cache. However, another thread may not see these uncommitted updates, leading to potential inconsistencies. volatile resolves this issue by ensuring proper commitment of writes, making the data visible to all threads.
Atomicity for Long and Double in 32-Bit Systems
In 32-bit systems, reading or writing to long and double types can result in non-atomic operations, potentially leading to "half-written" data. The volatile modifier ensures atomicity for these operations, even in such environments, safeguarding against such issues.
Memory Reordering and happens-before Guarantees
Even in single-processor systems, memory reordering can cause logical inconsistencies. For example, without volatile, a thread might observe an updated variable while other preceding updates remain unseen. The volatile keyword enforces happens-before guarantees, ensuring a consistent order of operations and preventing reorderings that could lead to unexpected results.

This section demonstrates that volatile serves critical purposes, even in seemingly straightforward single-processor setups. It addresses complexities like thread-local store buffers, atomicity concerns, and memory reordering.

Myth 4: Immediate Visibility of volatile Writes
One of the most pervasive misconceptions about volatile is the assumption that changes to a volatile field are immediately visible to all threads, as if they are written directly to main memory. This belief often stems from the first myth about bypassing caches. While the process is indeed fast, it is not instantaneous.
Cache Coherence and Commit Overheads
The efficiency of cache coherence protocols is remarkable but not without latency. When a value is committed from the store buffer, it can trigger cache invalidation across other cores if the same cache line exists in a Shared state. This forces the initiating thread to transition its cache line to Exclusive, requiring synchronization and potentially updating main memory.
This description applies primarily to the classical MESI protocol, which was implemented in earlier x86 processors (starting with Intel Pentium, P5 architecture). In these cases, synchronization with main memory was often necessary to ensure cache coherence when modified data could no longer be retained solely in one cache.
However, modern processors utilize more advanced cache coherence protocols, such as MESIF (used in Intel processors starting with Nehalem) and MOESI (used in AMD processors starting with Opteron). These protocols significantly reduce the need for main memory synchronization in scenarios involving modified data shared across multiple cores.

MESIF introduces the Forward (F) state, allowing a single core to act as the designated responder when multiple cores hold a cache line in the Shared state. This avoids unnecessary invalidations and eliminates redundant interactions with main memory for data that is already consistent across the caches.

MOESI extends MESI with the Owned (O) state, which enables modified data to reside in one cache while being simultaneously shared with other caches. The Owned state ensures that the core holding the data is responsible for responding to requests from other cores, bypassing the need for immediate write-back to main memory until the cache line is evicted.


In both MESIF and MOESI, these optimizations minimize the overhead associated with cache coherence. They also ensure that data can be efficiently shared between cores without triggering unnecessary invalidations or main memory updates.
It is also important to consider the role of Invalidation Queues in this process. When multiple invalidation requests are sent to a target core under high load, these requests are queued for sequential processing. If the queue becomes saturated, delays can occur as the system waits for the queue to clear. This means that the invalidation of a desired cache line may have to wait its turn in the queue. While these delays are typically short, they introduce non-zero latency, which can manifest unexpectedly in certain scenarios.
For frequent operations on volatile fields, while cache invalidations and transitions to Exclusive may still occur, the advanced features of MESIF and MOESI reduce the frequency and severity of these overheads. However, developers should remain aware of potential delays caused by Invalidation Queue saturation in high-throughput systems. These considerations highlight that while modern protocols improve performance significantly, achieving consistency across cores is still not instantaneous.

Reading From Cache
Importantly, even with volatile, caches remain in use for reads. After the coherence protocol completes, the latest value can be stored and accessed directly from the cache, ensuring consistency. The time required to invalidate other cache lines or update memory varies but is never instantaneous.
Practical Considerations
In high-throughput systems with intense volatile usage, the overhead becomes more pronounced. To avoid relying on immediate visibility, it’s crucial to verify changes explicitly using spin-wait loops or other mechanisms. This ensures that cache coherence protocols and happens-before guarantees have fully established visibility for the updated value and preceding writes.
In summary, while volatile enforces visibility, its effects depend on hardware synchronization, which is fast but not instantaneous.

Conclusion
In this section, we tackled several widespread myths surrounding the volatile keyword in Java, uncovering its true role and dispelling misconceptions. From cache usage to register interactions and its relevance in single-processor systems, we explored the nuances that define its behavior under the hood.
In the next part, we will delve into specific machine-level instructions and their relationship with volatile, providing a deeper technical understanding of how it integrates with modern hardware and the Java Memory Model. Stay tuned!
