# In x86-64 asm: is there a way of optimising two adjacent 32-bit stores / writes to memory if the source operands are two immediate values?

Tags: assembly, optimization, x86-64, micro-optimization

Is there a good way of optimising this code (x86-64) ?

```
mov dword ptr[rsp], 0;
mov dword ptr[rsp+4], 0
```

where the immediate values could be any values, not necessarily zero, but in this instance always immediate constants.

Is the original pair of stores even slow? Write-combining in the hardware and parallel operation of the μops might just make everything ridiculously fast anyway? I’m wondering if there is no problem to fix.

I’m thinking of something like (don’t know if the following instructions even exist)

```
mov  qword ptr[rsp], 0
```

or

```
mov  eax, 0;
mov  qword ptr[rsp], rax    ; assuming we can spare a register, a bad idea to corrupt one though
```

Comment: The most efficient way to zero a register is `xor eax, eax`.  It's all but free.

Comment: Yes, the instructions `mov qword ptr [rsp], 0` and `mov  eax, 0; mov  qword ptr[rsp], rax` exist.

Answer (score 7):

**Yes, compile-time / asm-source-level write-coalescing is often a good idea, especially if both or the high half is zero (or `-1`) so you can do the whole qword with 1 instruction**; modern x86 CPUs have efficient unaligned stores especially when it doesn't cross a cache line boundary.

You generally want to minimize total fused-domain uops (to get your code through the front-end as efficiently as possible), total code-size in bytes, and total unfused-domain uops (back end space in the scheduler / RS).  In something like that priority.  Also, there are uop-cache considerations for Sandybridge-family; 64-bit immediates, or 32-bit immediate + disp8/disp32, can need to borrow extra space from an adjacent entry in the uop cache line.  (See Agner Fog's microarch pdf on https://agner.org/optimize/, the Sandybridge chapter.  That still applies to later uarches like Skylake)

Also minimizing pressure on certain back-end execution ports that surrounding code uses heavily is good.  Ice Lake has 2 store-data and store-address ports so can run both stores in parallel, but before that all x86 CPUs are limited to 1 store per clock (having only a single store-data port to write data into the store buffer).  Commit to L1d cache is also limited to 1 store per clock from the store buffer.  Out-of-order exec does smooth that out so 2 stores back to back isn't a big problem, but 2x 4-byte immediate stores takes a lot of instruction size.

x86 unfortunately doesn't have a `mov r/m32, sign_extended_imm8`, only imm32. (https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/mov)  x86-64 *does* have `mov r/m64, sign_extended_imm32`, though, which is what you should use:

```
mov    qword [rsp], 0      ; 8 bytes, 1 fused-domain uop on modern Intel and AMD CPUs
```

vs. 7 bytes + 8 bytes and 2 uops for `mov  dword [rsp],0` / `mov dword [rsp+4], 0`.  xor-zeroing EAX / storing RAX would be smaller (code size), but cost 2 uops instead of 1.

> assuming we can spare a register, a bad idea to corrupt one though

Hardly; you often have a use for a zeroed register, and [xor-zeroing is literally as cheap as a NOP on Sandybridge-family](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33666617/what-is-the-best-way-to-set-a-register-to-zero-in-x86-assembly-xor-mov-or-and).  (And also cheap on AMD.)  If you can do this store somewhere that makes it useful to have a zeroed register, this is very cheap:

```
xor   eax, eax
mov  [rsp], rax         ; better if you have a use for RAX later
```

Or for non-zero 64-bit values where you want `mov r64, imm64`, it's typical that you have a spare register you could use as a scratch destination.  If you would have to spill a register or save/restore an extra reg around the whole function, then it's probably better to just do 2 separate dword-immediate stores if you can't do a single sign-extended-imm32.

---

For non-zero constants, if the whole qword constant can be represented as a sign-extended 32-bit immediate, use `mov  qword [rsp], imm32`.  (Or `push imm32` and optimize away an earlier `sub rsp, 8`.)

If you know your qword memory location is 8-byte aligned, then it's worth combining even for an arbitrary 8-byte constant that doesn't fit in a 32-bit immediate:

```
mov  rax, 0x123456789abcdef0        ; 10 bytes, 1 uop
mov  [rsp], rax                     ; 4 bytes, 1 micro-fused uop, for port 4 + port 2,3, or 7
```

It's only somewhat better than doing 2 separate dword stores, and could be slower in the (probably?) rare case where it crosses a 64-byte cache-line boundary

```
mov  dword [rsp], 0x9abcdef0        ; 7 bytes, 1 micro-fused uop for port 4 + port 2,3, or 7
mov  dword [rsp+4], 0x12345678      ; 8 bytes, 1 micro-fused uop for port 4 + port 2,3, or 7
```

Or if your constant happens to fit in a 32-bit value *zero-extended* to 64-bit, but not sign-extended, you can `mov eax, 0x87654321` (5 bytes, very efficient) / `mov [rsp], rax`.

---

**If you want to do a qword reload later, definitely do a single qword store so store-forwarding can work efficiently**.

---

> Write-combining in the hardware

That's not the major factor.  More important is OoO exec and the store buffer decoupling store execution from the surrounding code.

If you *were* actually hoping to get more than 1 store (of any width) per clock executed, you're definitely out of luck on uarches before Ice Lake.  On any uarch (even non-x86), hardware store-coalescing happens after stores execute.

You're also out of luck if you're hoping it will coalesce and take fewer entries in the store buffer so it has more time / room to absorb two cache-miss stores.  We don't have any real evidence of any x86 doing that to save store-buffer-drain bandwidth, or free up store-buffer entries sooner.  See [Why doesn't RFO after retirement break memory ordering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62376976/why-doesnt-rfo-after-retirement-break-memory-ordering) for my current understanding of (lack-of) store buffer coalescing.  There's some evidence that Intel at least can commit store misses to LFBs on cache-miss stores to free up space in the store buffer, but only with the limits of program order, and no evidence of committing multiple per clock.

Comment: I started thinking about this because of poor code generation that I noticed from GCC and LLVM back ends (in the Dlang language, from the GDC and LDC compilers both) where they fail to do this optimisation with two imm32’s, which happened to both be zero in the case I noticed.

Comment: I wonder if anyone could report that weakness in the two back ends for me good people - I ask because I’m in very poor health and simple tasks are proving a nightmare

Comment: @CecilWard: Are you sure you enabled optimization?  LDC and GDC both do it at `-O2`, https://godbolt.org/z/65Mrdd.  Just like GCC and clang both do this for C/C++ https://godbolt.org/z/7zv1P7.  In general, x86-64 compiler back-ends do know about this optimization.  If you have a [mcve] where they miss it, please link it on Godbolt so someone can make a bug report out of it.

Comment: They were two 32-bit words on the stack : https://godbolt.org/z/xao1x9

Comment: @CecilWard:  Reproducible in C as well: https://godbolt.org/z/bWf5Ev.  Ah right, in my example the compiler knew early on that the dword objects were adjacent (because they were array elements).  In yours, they're separate D (or C) objects; the compiler probably doesn't "think of" them as adjacent until it's doing stack-frame layout, presumably after whatever optimization pass looks for store merging.  I assume this is a known bug; GCC was missing store coalescing entirely from GCC3 (regression from 2.95 IIRC) until GCC8, like 15 or 20 years.  So apparently it's not trivial. :P

Comment: If/when I get around to it, I'll file GCC / LLVM bugs, or someone else can.  I don't see an open GCC bug for this store merging/coalescing/combining missed-optimization bug.

Comment: Indeed, thought of as separate objects, so the opportunity for checking for coalescence opportunities would have to come later on and it would be awkward to find the right place to put such a transformation poss ? I haven’t tried structs‘ fields, you tried arrays.

Comment: @CecilWard: I think modern GCC / LLVM *do* handle merging for struct members.

Comment: Great answer, Peter.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can combine your two 32-bit writes into a single 64-bit write, like so:

```
mov     QWORD PTR [rsp], 0
```

The immediate value is a 32-bit sign extended immediate, so it's not this simple if your second write is non-zero<sup>1</sup>, or if the MSB of the first write is 1. In that case, you can load a 64-bit constant using `movabs` and write that. E.g., to write 1 and 2,

```
movabs  rax,  0x200000001
mov     QWORD PTR [rsp], rax
```

The constant `0x200000001` results in the right values being written into each 32-bit half.

This trick is definitely worth it for the zero case and maybe worth it for the non-zero case and [Peter's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62975579/149138) goes into much more detail on the tradeoffs in that latter case.

Compilers can also make this optimization (they call it "store combining" or something like that), meaning you can play with this [on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/49x7o5).

---

<sup>1</sup> Except in the special case that the sign extension gives you exactly what you want. I.e., the second value is exactly `0xFFFFFFFF` and the high bit of the first value is set.