# Using Intel's SHA256 instructions on AMD Epyc seems to be slower than not using hardware acceleration at all

Tags: assembly, x86, cryptography, sha256, sha

I'm using Intel's SHA hardware acceleration instructions (`sha256rnds2`, etc, [implementation here](https://github.com/noloader/SHA-Intrinsics/blob/master/sha256-x86.c)) and I have a speed around 30% slower than  OpenSSL's software SHA256.

I'm doing a single SHA256 round (64 bytes), twice. As a comparision, I have around 100 M/s without SHA256 at all, 50 M/s with OpenSSL's SHA256 (two rounds of 64 bytes each) and 35 M/s using Intel's SHA instructions.

With 60 GHz (24 * 2.5 GHz [ * 2 HT]), that's around 600 cycles going to the two soft SHA256 rounds, while the same using accelerated instructions takes around 1100 cycles.

Is this expected?

Comment: How's the single-threaded performance?  It seems unlikely that multiple cores compete with each other for a shared crypto unit, though.  ([Agner Fog's measurements for Ryzen's `sha256rnds2` instruction are 1 uop with 4 cycle latency, one per 2 cycle throughput](http://agner.org/optimize/) The surrounding code you linked has a lot of shuffles, too.)

Comment: Did you compile with optimization enabled?  What compiler / options did you use exactly?  Does your benchmark fit purely in L1D / L1I cache of each core you're running it on?

Comment: Enabling optimisations revelaled some compiler warning for a buffer I was using wrong that was causing the speed penality. I now got to 85M/s using the hardware instructions, that is not perfect, but still pretty good. I believe I still might have some margin to optimise it further. Thank you Peter! (I'm sorry but it looks like I can't upvote your comment).

Comment: Benchmarking with optimization disabled is insane anyway.  It hurts SIMD intrinsics just as much, if not more, than scalar code.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32000917/c-loop-optimization-help-for-final-assignment/32001196#32001196